# Javascript file not functioning when included in html with correct format

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have jquery included in the header alongside my js file and the format is correct, but it just doesn't seem to want to work.

Here is the header for the storepage.php file that needs the js file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/CSS/design.css">
    <title>GET YOUR KEYS HERE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/storePage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/addTag.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
```

and here is the beginning of the javascript file

```
function tester() {
    console.log("Checking document status...");
}


console.log("Checking document status...");
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Nothing shows up in console, so I am a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: Any errors on console?

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling your function inside your **`document.ready()`** method to make it run after the document is loaded:

```
function tester() {
    console.log("Checking document status...")
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  tester()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why nothing show in your console?

1. Cause you not call your `tester()` function when the document is ready.
2. Your document ready syntax is wrong.

What you need is, write true document ready syntax like this, and call your `tester()` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  tester();
  console.log('testing'); //call the console log manually when the document ready.
});
```